# Avoid Duplicate in Creating a Google Calendar Event - Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have the code below that creates a calendar event in Google Calendar using google Apps Script.

```
function createCalendarEvent(){
       let adoptionCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("a16cod711vq2qn7gcd6tcua9i4@group.calendar.google.com");   
       adoptionCalendar.createEvent('Alabama', new Date('August 20, 2022 00:00:00 GMT-7'), new Date('August 20, 2022 23:59:59 GMT-7'));
}
```

Everytime. I run the code, it creates and add the event in my Google Calendar. How to do checking first, if the event already exist. If the event exist already, we should not add anymore the event.

Another solution, is to delete all the events in my Calendar and write all my events again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for an existing event if if it doesn't exist it will create one.  Otherwise it will do nothing.  Just be careful with the dates.

The first time I run this I see "created".  If I run it again I don't.

I got the search options from another post on SO so I can't attest to them.

```
function addEvent() {
  // Explanation of how the search section works (as it is NOT quite like most things Google) as part of the getEvents function:
  //    {search: 'word1'}              Search for events with word1
  //    {search: '-word1'}             Search for events without word1
  //    {search: 'word1 word2'}        Search for events with word2 ONLY
  //    {search: 'word1-word2'}        Search for events with ????
  //    {search: 'word1 -word2'}       Search for events without word2
  //    {search: 'word1+word2'}        Search for events with word1 AND word2
  //    {search: 'word1+-word2'}       Search for events with word1 AND without word2
  //    {search: '-word1+-word2'}      Search for events without word1 AND without word2 (I find this to work logically like an 'OR' statement)
  try {
    let calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
    let events = calendar.getEvents( new Date('August 20, 2022 00:00:00 GMT-7'), new Date('August 20, 2022 23:59:59 GMT-7'), { search: 'Alabama'} );
    if( events.length === 0 ) {
      calendar.createEvent('Alabama', new Date('August 20, 2022 00:00:00 GMT-7'), new Date('August 20, 2022 23:59:59 GMT-7'));
      console.log("created");
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [Calendar.getEvent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date,Object))